# How to grow bright pixels in grey region? OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

How can I grow bright pixel in grey region?

Input:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpE0m.png)

Output: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQBql.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give us an idea how much of the API involved you have already understood, and where your problems start.

Comment: How much do you want to grow it by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is somewhat less helpful than my usual efforts, but it is hard to get up enthusiasm for questions with so little effort...

You can solve your issue by using **OpenCV** `findContours()` - documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours). You will need to be sure to use the retrieval mode `CV_RETR_TREE`.

You then need to write a loop, iterating through all the contours found. In the loop, you need to look for a contour that:

- a) has a colour of `white` and,
- b) which has a parent with colour `grey`.

There is a decent explanation of how the hierarchy works [here](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2013/01/contours-5-hierarchy.html).

Comment: Thanks for your consideration.
I resolved it with contours and floodfill

Answer (score 2):

```
Mat im = imread("ask.png", 0);
Mat mat;
mat = im==255;
    findContours( mat, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    for( size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
      {
        floodFill(mat, contours[i].at(0), 255, 0, Scalar(128), Scalar(255), FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE);
      }
    mat = mat==255;                // output image
```